# How to solve the loading error of clang's Python binding?

Tags: python, c++, macos, dll, clang

I'm trying the Python binding for clang. I installed LLVM and its python bindings using `homebrew` on Mac OS X Maverics with command line

```
 brew install llvm --with-clang --with-python --with-lld
```

The loading code is

```
import clang
import clang.cindex

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path('/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib')
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
```

But this throws an error:

> clang.cindex.LibclangError:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib/libclang.dylib, 6): Library
>   not loaded: @rpath/libLLVM-3.5.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib/libclang.dylib   Reason: image not
>   found. To provide a path to libclang use Config.set_library_path() or
>   Config.set_library_file().

But I don't understand why this error occurs. Doesn't `@rpath` here refers to `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib`? But there *is* a file called `libLLVM-3.5.dylib` under that directory. Why does this loading cause an error and how to fix it?

Comment: It's probably build with the wrong architecture or only one architecture (not a fat binary?) (verify using file /path/to/file) - if you're using the system python it needs to be a universal binary for it to work right. brew is terrible in general especially for convergence issues like this, your best bet is to build your llvm from scratch following their directions. brew is great if you're busy and just need simple commands, but when you're using projects that require multiple frameworks / libraries to be in sync, it is a total crap shoot.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: It is built for 64 bit and Python is of 64 bit. And in fact, it is not a Python issue after all. I tried linking to that `libclang` in c++ and the resulting executable also throws such error.

Comment: Try adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib/ to your environment?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: OK, that works. I was trying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before. And why is `@rpath` not pointing to the library dir?

Comment: @rpath is 'relative' path, usually for App bundles.. unsure how the behavior should work for stuff with /usr/local/lib/.. You might be able to have the python script modify your environment before you import the clang stuff to have a load-once-and-forget solution, i.e. os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PREL...'] = '/foo/bar'; import clang; .. For more details on how it works you can do 'man dyld' which provides all the options available, there's some useful debugging flags that might explain what logic is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A robust alternative is to use `Config.set_library_path`**, works great in interactive Python (IPython, Jupyter) too.

```
from clang.cindex import Index,Config,CursorKind

# check where is LLVM installed on your machine (here on MacOS)
Config.set_library_path('/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.3/lib')

SCRIPT_PATH = './tcpdump/print-ppp.c'

# C99 is a proper compiler for tcpdump, as per their docs
index = Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse(SCRIPT_PATH, args=['-std=c99'])
```

This is also [recommended in docs](https://libclang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/clang/cindex.html).

Answer (score 2):

Elevating @synthesizerpatel's comment to an answer:

Add the following environment variable to your environment:

```
 DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib/
```

The [readme](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/clang/bindings/python) also mentions

> You may need to alter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that the Clang library can be found.